# What characters are special in an nginx map instruction?

Tags: nginx, http

I'm moving a site to a new structure and want to use nginx's map to map old URLs to their new locations. For simple cases that works like a charm, but I have trouble with some values. This is what I tried:

```
   /old/page1.htm /new/info.html;
```

works like a charm. Then I tries these:

```
/stw/wisselblog.nsf/0485b0c9032c281ac1257b10001decbb/839ed94b2337e5634825737600305ecf/entryrich/0.204?openelement&fieldelemformat=gif /blog/images/rtimg/23.gif;
```

in the variation above and then with backslash only on the `&` `?` and `=` and any combination of backslahes before the three.

none of these works. I get the error: `nginx: [emerg] conflicting parameter`.

In case you think the first URL is made up, [look for yourself](http://www.wissel.net/stw/wisselblog.nsf/0485b0c9032c281ac1257b10001decbb/839ed94b2337e5634825737600305ecf/entryrich/0.204?openelement&fieldelemformat=gif)

What do I miss?

**Update**: the mapping isn't regex capable since the file names change.

Comment: That old URL is ... completely ridiculous. Have you got any other examples? Is there really nothing in common about them?

Comment: It is actually real. That's the reason I want to clean up. And yes there is nothing common!

Answer (score 1):

Aaarrgh...

I was barking up the wrong tree! The characters work just fine. In the map file (which is a few thousand lines long) I had a duplicate key. so the `conflicting parameter` actually means **duplicate key in map**